# Unable to import Quality Profile Ruleset in Sonar 5.2

Tags: java, curl, sonarqube

I have a backup of ruleset from Sonar 3.7.x and want to import into Sonar 5.2. This ruleset has rules for PMD, CheckStyle and Findbugs. When I try through GUI the import works without any error but no rules are imported (0 rules). Then I tried the Sonar API to import the ruleset using curl. Here also the command succeeds although the results (ruleFailures:600) show that no rules out of the 600 in the XML were imported (same behavior as the GUI).

```
-bash-4.1$ curl -X POST -u admin:admin -F "backup=@My_standard_java_600.xml" -v http://XX.XX.40.70:9080/api/profiles/restore
* About to connect() to XX.XX.40.70 port 9080 (#0)
* Trying XX.XX.40.70... connected
* Connected to XX.XX.40.70 (XX.XX.40.70) port 9080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> POST /api/profiles/restore HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.14.3.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: XX.XX.40.70:9080
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 105883
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------b413fb6533eb
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=CE9FC5FE32939BE5ECC4FC64324B238D; Path=/; HttpOnly
< X-Runtime: 16162
< ETag: "c48a79cd01c8066aa814d5755e0c29ed"
< Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 194
< Date: Wed, 02 Dec 2015 15:16:15 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host XX.XX.40.70 left intact
* Closing connection #0
{"profile":{"key":"java-my-standard-63451","name":"My Standard","language":"java","isDefault":false,"isInherited":false,"languageName":"Java"},"ruleSuccesses":0,"ruleFailures":600}
```

I compared the Sonar-way Java rule export with my file and I don't find that the XML format may have changed from v3.x to 5.x. Can any Sonar expert please help troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: do you have the Checkstyle, PMD and FindBugs plugins installed? IIRC, with 3.2 they were part of the distribution, but that's no longer the case.

Comment: Thanks a lot G.Ann, in fact that has been the issue. I installed all these plugins as they are no longer supported out of the box in favor of Squid. And the import worked, but bit annoying on part of Sonar to not hint me to the real cause for not importing the rules ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by G.Ann's comments above the issue pertained to missing Findbugs, Checkstyle and PMD plugins in the new Sonar 5.2 installation as they are no longer supported out of the box in favor of Squid. Once installed the import worked, though bit annoying on part of Sonar to not hint to the real cause for not importing the rule.